# JavaScript: Understanding cases in switch

Tags: javascript, scope

I'm in JavaScript for a while, but there is still soo much things to learn.

Now, I had found some interesting facts about *Switch statement*.

I know that when you use *case `someValue`:* without *break;* it execute code in next case.

```
switch (x) {
  case 0:
  case 1:
    doThis();
  case 2:
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
}
```

So, when *`x`* is `0` or `1` it execute *`doThis()`* and even *`doSomethingElse()`*, **but why?**.
Will JavaScript interpret it into something like this:

```
switch (x) {
  case (0 == x || 1 == x): 
    doThis();
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
  case (2 == x):
    doSomethingElse();
    break;
}
```

or it creates code block for every case until brek appears, like this:

```
switch (x) {
  case 0: {
    case 1: {
      doThis();
      case 2: {
        doSomethingElse();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

*Statements will be probraly rather this: `(x === 0 && x == 0) || x === 1 && x == 1)`*

If it first case that I show, then why it not works when you write it with those conditions? And second case that I show is only very unclear idea, how it can works.

**Can anybody explain it to me?** Thanks.

Comment: the comparison is always strict in switch/case statements.

Comment: the first matching `case x` is the entry point. After that it just executes the code line by line until it hits a break condition (ie. a `break`, a `return` or the end of the `switch` block*)

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli it can be a `continue` too if the `switch` is inside a loop.

Comment: @Dmitry indeed, and there might be more. it was not meant to be an exhaustive list :)

Comment: More like the second one, yes, but *without* the blocks. The whole `switch` body is a single scope block.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is a flow with three lanes, where one lane it the outer *program flow*, a *check lane* and a *case lane*.

A change of a lane happens with a `case` statement, which yields `true` with a [strict check](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators) of the expression of the `switch` statement and the value of the `case` clause, then you go to the *case lane* and stays as long as you not reach either `break` or the end of the `switch` statement.

As long as you are still in the *check lane*, any `break` statement between other checks or the end does not have any effect.

```
                        out    lane  lane
code                    side  check  case  comment
---------------------  -----  -----  ----  -------------------------------------------------
                          v
switch (x) {              v >>>  v       
  case 0:                        ? >>> v   if case is true, change lane
  case 1:                        ? >>> v   if case is true, change lane
    doThis();                    v     v
  case 2:                        ? >>> v   if case is true, change lane
    doSomethingElse();           v     v
    break;                v <<<<<<<<<< .   break statement, back to program flow
  default:                v      ? >>> v   change lane if value is not in other case clauses
                          v      v
}                         v <<<  .         end of switch
                          v
```

Comment: ASCII art at it's finest :)

Answer (score 3):

## Review of structure of `switch` <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch)</sup>

It would be worth remembering the structure of `switch`

```
switch (expression) {
case value1:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches value1
    [break;]
case value2:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches value2
    [break;]
...
case valueN:
    //Statements executed when the
    //result of expression matches valueN
    [break;]
[default:
    //Statements executed when none of
    //the values match the value of the expression
    [break;]]
}
```

### What happens if I forget a break on a switch? (JS) <sup>[1](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch)</sup>

If you forget a `break`, the script will execute **from where the condition is fulfilled and will execute the following`case` independently if this condition is fulfilled or not**.

> ### Example 01

```js
// EXAMPLE01
    var x = 1;
    switch (x) {
        case 0:
        case 1: // x is 1, therefore the condition is fulfilled and the next block is executed
            doThis ();
            // NOTE: the forgotten "break" should be here
        case 2: // There is no "break" sentence in the 'case 12:', therefore this case will also be executed
            doSomethingElse ();
            break; // When finding a "break", the 'case 2:' will not be executed.
        default:
            console.log ('default');
    }

    /**
    * Testing functions
    */

    function doThis () {
        console.log ('This case is one');
    }

    function doSomethingElse () {
        console.log ('This case is two');
    }
```

> ### [image: Status]Tips
>
> ---
>
> Whenever a switch is executed, it should be put `default` so that if it does not find the expected in the`case` finalize, with a desired action.

## Comparisons in JS in switch

To compare, we must use the equality and identity comparators and if logic is necessary (*See more in [Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators)*) :

> ### Example 02-A

```js
    // EXAMPLE 02.A
    var x = 2;
    switch (true) {
        case (x === 1 || x === 0): // Not true when x = 2;
            doThis ();
            doSomethingElse ();
            break;
        case (x === 2): // Will be executed
            doSomethingElse ();
            break;
        default:
            console.log ('default');
    }

    /**
    * Testing functions
    */

    function doThis () {
        console.log ('This case is one');
    }

    function doSomethingElse () {
        console.log ('This case is two');
    }
```

Or we could also use the `<` or `>` operators:

> ### Example 02-B

```js
    // EXAMPLE 02.B
    x = 2;
    switch (true) {
        case (x === 1 || x === 0): // Not true when x = 2;
            doThis ();
            doSomethingElse ();
            break;
        case (x> 1 || x> 3): // Will be executed
            doSomethingElse ();
            break;
        default:
            console.log ('default');
    }
    /**
     * Testing functions
     */

    function doThis () {
        console.log ('This case is one');
    }

    function doSomethingElse () {
        console.log ('This case is two');
    }
```

### Run a nested switch

To make a switch with a more advanced level in terms of comparison you could use conditional (*`if ... else`, etc*) or loops as `continue`.

> ### Example 03

```js
// EXAMPLE 03
var x = 2;
switch (true) {
    case (x === 1 || x === 0):
        doThis ();
        doSomethingElse ();
        break;
    case (x> 1 || x> 4): // Will be executed
        if (x === 1) {
            // It will not run
            console.log ('Its not the desired number');
        } else if (x === 2) {// It will be executed and it will end
            doSomethingElse ()
        }
        break;
    default:
        console.log ('default');
}
/**
 * Testing functions
 */

function doThis () {
    console.log ('This case is one');
}

function doSomethingElse () {
    console.log ('This case is two(2)');
}
```

> ## ✏️ Annotations

#### Differences between `===` and `==` <sup>[3](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/331/diferencias-entre-y-comparaciones-en-javascript)</sup>

The `===` and `! ==` operators are the *strict* comparison operators. This means that if the operands have different types, they are not the same. For example,

```
1 === "1" // false
1! == "1" // true
null === undefined // false
```

The operators `==` and `! =` Are the comparison operators *relaxed*. That is, if the operands have different types, JavaScript tries to convert them to be comparable. For example,

```
1 == "1" // true
1! = "1" // false
null == undefined // true
```

It is worth mentioning that the operator `==` is not [transitive](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/switch), unlike `===`.

```
"0" == 0 // true
0 == "" // true
"0" == "" // false
```