# javascript unexpected behavior on switch statement

Tags: javascript

Hello I'm using node js v12.10 and the following code don´t work properly

```
let number = 0x10
switch(number){    
    case 0x10:
        console.log('0x10')        
    case 0x16:
        console.log('0x16')
        break
    default:
        console.log(number)
        break
}
```

the output is:
0x10
0x16

I know that I forget the break instruction on case 0x10, but still the case 0x16 should not be executed.
Is that a bug?

Comment: that's the default behavior.

Comment: Reading the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) is always useful.

Comment: if you won't provide break statement it will execute the next case until it find the break statement

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please try searching before posting a new query. Refer the answers to this question for understanding on the working of Switch-Case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377350/javascript-understanding-cases-in-switch

Comment: "The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If break is omitted, the program continues  execution at the next statement in the switch statement. " - quoted from MDN docs

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it's a feature not a bug. It is very useful when you want to group several cases like so:

```
const errorcode = 'EADDRINUSE'
switch(errorcode){    
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
    case 'ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED':
        console.log('connection error')
        break
    case '502':
    case '404':
        console.log('server error')
    default:
        console.log('general error')
        break
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a language feature. It's sometimes called 'switch statement fallthrough'.