# Let execute next case code in a javascript switch statement is a bad practice?

Tags: javascript

Is it a bad practice to take advantage of the fact that in a javascript switch if there is no break then
the execution thread will continue in the next case ?

```
switch (key) {
  case value:
    /* code executed here */            
  // break;          
  default:
    /* more code executed here */ 
  break;
}
```

Comment: if you need it, why not?

Comment: it's not a bad practice.

Comment: maybe you have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377350/javascript-understanding-cases-in-switch/54377551#54377551

Comment: I don't think it's bad practice but it seems fairly uncommon. Can you provide a specific example of how you want to use it?

Comment: I use it (not often, but not uncommonly) so I consider it a good practice. I remember reading somewhere that this behavior actually was one of the reasons to make it "standard" code structure among many languages (cannot find a reference quickly). It would be better to discuss something specific. Can you please provide complete code showing your concerns? A sample toy code is fine, just fill `/* code executed here */` with some actual code.