# Can I set up a switch statement to remember what to do with the output as well as the input in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, switch-statement, control-flow

As a part of a Codecademy beginner JavaScript exercise, I have written the following code.

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
let eightBall = ""

switch (randomNumber) {
  case 0:
    eightBall = "It is certain";
  case 1:
    eightBall = "It is decidedly so";
  case 2:
    eightBall = "Reply hazy try again";
  case 3:
    eightBall = "Cannot predict now";
  case 4:
    eightBall = "Do not count on it";
  case 5:
    eightBall = "My sources say no";
  case 6:
    eightBall = "Outlook not so good";
  case 7:
    eightBall = "The eight ball answered: Signs point to yes";
}

console.log(eightBall)
```

Switch statements seem to work really well, but I can't help noticing the inefficiency of rewriting `eightBall =`  for every case. Does anyone know of a way to eliminate this and tell the switch control flow to do something with every output uniformly? My current best guess is a dictionary (which I'm familiar with through learning Python) but I would rather hear of a way to do it still using the switch statement.

Comment: You do realize that every run of this, regardless of the random number, will always output "The eight ball answered: Signs point to yes" - right?

Comment: I made your snippet runnable so you can see that for yourself.

Comment: haha, @JacobK use breaks for each case and switch statement executes only one case at one time if you use break at each level. you can use objects also (similar to dictionary in python)

Comment: @RandyCasburn this is because of the lack of break statements, correct?

Comment: Yes...it is. Have fun with this stuff!

Answer (score 1):

Your [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) approach falls through all cases and takes the last assignent as result. To prevent this you could take a [`break` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break). This ends the `switch` statement.

For a deeper understanding of `break`, you may have a look here: [JavaScript: Understanding cases in switch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54377350/javascript-understanding-cases-in-switch/54377551#54377551).

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
let eightBall = ""

switch (randomNumber) {
  case 0:
    eightBall = "It is certain";
    break;
  case 1:
    eightBall = "It is decidedly so";
    break;
  case 2:
    eightBall = "Reply hazy try again";
    break;
  case 3:
    eightBall = "Cannot predict now";
    break;
  case 4:
    eightBall = "Do not count on it";
    break;
  case 5:
    break;
    eightBall = "My sources say no";
  case 6:
    eightBall = "Outlook not so good";
    break;
  case 7:
    eightBall = "The eight ball answered: Signs point to yes";
    break;
}

console.log(eightBall);
```

A shorter approach could take an array with all phrases.

```js
let phrases = ["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Reply hazy try again", "Cannot predict now", "Do not count on it", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "The eight ball answered: Signs point to yes"],
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8),
    eightBall = phrases[randomNumber];

console.log(eightBall);
```

Comment: perhaps your missed this from the OP: "_I would rather hear of a way to do it still using the switch statement._"

Answer (score 0):

Your original code is actually incorrect since you did not add `break` after any case, so it will always set `eightBall` to the default value. If all of the possible values are integers not too far apart, you can use array indexes.

```js
let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 8);
const values = ["It is certain", "It is decidedly so", "Reply hazy try again", "Cannot predict now", "Do not count on it", "My sources say no", "Outlook not so good", "The eight ball answered: Signs point to yes"];
let eightBall = values[randomNumber];
console.log(eightBall)
```

Comment: perhaps your missed this from the OP: "_I would rather hear of a way to do it still using the switch statement._"

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone know of a way to eliminate this and tell the switch control flow to do something with every output uniformly?

No, there is no way. A `switch` statement contains statements, and these don't have "outputs". They must do the assignments on their own, each of them.

There are proposals to extend the language with case *expressions* to achieve this, e.g. the [pattern-matching proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-pattern-matching), but none of these are accepted into the standard yet.

But as you say, for use cases like this a dictionary (`Map` or object literal in JS) or -- for integer indices - just an array is the more appropriate solution anyway.